# Spark - MLlib Obtain loss (cost/error) history from LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I am using `Apache-Spark` to perform logistic regression w/ LBFGS. I am trying to generate [Learning Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve) to see whether my model is suffering from high bias or high variance.

Andrew Ng discusses the usefulness of learning curves in his [Lecture on Learning Curves](https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture/64) from his [Machine Learning Coursera Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning). To accomplish this, I will need to obtain the loss AKA cost AKA error of the optimization function.

The Apache src contains the following in [LBFGS.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/LBFGS.scala)

```
@DeveloperApi
object LBFGS extends Logging {

  ... some code

  def runLBFGS(...some params...): (Vector, Array[Double]) = {
      val lossHistory = mutable.ArrayBuilder.make[Double]

      ... more code

      var state = states.next()
      while (states.hasNext) {
        lossHistory += state.value
        state = states.next()
      }
      lossHistory += state.value
      val lossHistoryArray = lossHistory.result()
      logInfo("LBFGS.runLBFGS finished. Last 10 losses %s".format(
        lossHistoryArray.takeRight(10).mkString(", ")))
      (weights, lossHistoryArray)
  }
```

I can see these weights displayed in the logs, but I am not sure how to obtain them programmatically using `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().run()`

My Attempt:

```
val (model, lossHistoryArray) = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
  .setNumClasses(2)
  .run(learningSample)
```

However, I get the error:

> constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
>   [error]  found   : (T1, T2)
>   [error]  required: org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel

The cause is obvious. However, I am not sure how to get the information I need, because it seems to be nested very deep within the API.